# Group or cluster nodes with same node attribute with Cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I thought of doing it by passing position to all nodes but since the graph is formed when the user 'uploads a file', I can't have the position set earlier itself for this. Can you please suggest what to do here?

```
elements:[

"data": {"id":"a", "group":"g1", ....}
"data": {"id":"b", "group":"g1", ....}
"data": {"id":"c", "group":"g2", ....}
"data": {"id":"d", "group":"g3", ....}

.... ]
```

So, in this case, I'd like to see nodes with IDs "a" and "b" sort of form or stick closer and away from other nodes so as to show that these two belong to a single group.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parent` field to group or cluster the nodes in your graph.
The field `group` can have two values 'nodes' or 'edges' which helps Cytoscape understand the element type.

In your case, we can do like:

```
elements = [
  { data: { id: "a", label: "a", group: "nodes", parent: "p1" } },
  { data: { id: "b", label: "b", group: "nodes", parent: "p1" } },
  { data: { id: "c", label: "c", group: "nodes", parent: "p2" } },
  { data: { id: "d", label: "d", group: "nodes", parent: "p2" } },
  { data: { id: "e", label: "e", group: "nodes", parent: "p2" } },
  { data: { id: "p1", label: "p1", group: "nodes" } },
  { data: { id: "p2", label: "p2", group: "nodes" } }
];
```

[Screenshot of the arrangement achieved with the above snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NieYV.png)

Here, the ids `a` and `b` have `p1` as parent so they will form a group and likewise, ids `c`, `d` and `e` will form a group under parent `p2`.
In order for the group node to be visible, we need to add a `group: 'nodes'` type object in the elements array.

Comment: Thanks and one more doubt I had was if you gave the coordinates for positions manually? If yes, then this wouldn't help me out as the number of nodes and edges keeps varying in my graph and I can't provide coordinate positions beforehand ....

Comment: So, there are two ways, cytoscape also has algorithms to find the `(x,y)` for nodes. Other way is to use `preset` algorithm and pass `(x,y)` with the nodes as keys in the node object.